# add and remove TR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table id="tab" border="2">
    <tbody>
        <tr> <td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>
        <tr> <td>bbb</td><td>bbb</td></tr>
        <tr> <td><select id="sel">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
</select></td><td>ccc</td></tr>
        <tr> <td>xxx</td><td>xxx</td></tr>
        <tr> <td>yyy</td><td>yyy</td></tr>
        <tr> <td>zzz</td><td>zzzz</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$("#sel").change(function(){

    if($(this).val() == 'three'){

       $('#tab').append('<tr><td>new</td><td>new</td></tr>');
    }

});
```

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/jSMBZ/4/

How can I modify this script so that if I select `three`, I add a new `<tr>` to the table. If I select either `one` or `two`, then I need to remove this new `<tr>` (if it exists).

edit: i updated my example

Comment: What are you asking here? If I understand your question, then you want to add a specific new row when you select option 'three', but remove that row whenever 'one' or 'two' is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the new row right below the select, or in other words, you want it to be the first row on the table then you would use `prepend` instead. Some code below...

```
$("#sel").change(function(){ 

    if( $(this).val() === 'three' )
        $('#tab').prepend('<tr class="new"><td>new</td><td>new</td></tr>'); 
    else 
        $('#tab tr.new').remove();    

});
```

Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/PRu6c/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will work for your needs:

I added a class to the newly created row, called `new` as such:

```
$('#tab').append("<tr class='new'><td>new</td><td>new</td></tr>");
```

whenever a selection is made other than `three`, it simply removes that row:

```
$(".new").remove();
```

**Full Code:**

```
$("#sel").change(function(){ 

    if($(this).val() == 'three'){
       $('#tab').append("<tr class='new'><td>new</td><td>new</td></tr>");
    }else{
       $('.new').remove(); 
    }        
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jSMBZ/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Simply specify some marker for new row. Here I used id: http://jsfiddle.net/jSMBZ/2/

Just remove marked `tr` if you change to some other value then `three`

```
$("#sel").change(function(){ 
    if($(this).val() == 'three'){
       $('#tab').append('<tr id="added"><td>new</td><td>new</td></tr>');
    } else {
       $('#tab tr#added').remove();
    }      
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set `class` attribute on the `<tr>` you've added.

I don't know how clever you wanted it, but I've [updated your example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jSMBZ/3/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `remove()`

```
$('#tab tbody tr').last().remove();
```